# Greek letters into upgreek in math mode

Tags: math-mode, greek

Is there a command to map every greek letter typed to its upgreek version?
E.g. if one types `$\theta$` they obtain `$\uptheta$`.

Comment: If you're not stuck to the default fontsd, there are some font packages that propose  the option `upright` or `frenchstyle` (`fourier, kpfonts, mathdesign,...`).

Answer (score 3):

You can redirect all Greek characters like the below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} 
\usepackage{upgreek} 
\let\alpha\upalpha 
\let\beta\upbeta %..etc for every greek command 
\begin{document} 
$\alpha$ 
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Sebastiano Done...

Comment: Without my name...:-) :-) the answer is your.